# Hibernate getting attribute which is in the table but not in the class

Tags: hibernate

I am using hibernate OneToOne mapping(using Foreign key) to join USER(userName(pk),firstName,LastName) with Address(addressId(PK,autogenerated),street,city,state). 
This operation creates a addressId column in USER table.
Now while logging in, I want to fetch address details using userName, How should I go about it.
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just rough Idea but this has to be done in this way,Try it

```
public class User{
    //other field
    Address address= new Address();

    // getter and setter here
}

public class Address{
    //address field

    // getter and setter here
}

//To get address
User user = getUserByName('xyz');
Address address = user.getAddress();
//use your address object
```